# How to remove values from an array if occurring more than one time?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, filtering

I need to remove values from an array that occur more than one time in the array.

For example:

```
$value = array(10,10,5,8);
```

I need this result:

```
$value = array(5,8);
```

Is there any in-built function in php?

I tried this, but this will not return my expected result:

```
$unique = array_unique($value);
$dupes = array_diff_key($value, $unique);
```

Comment: Check out the [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), then you should be able to come up with something yourself. If you have a specific problem with implementing your idea, show us your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: $unique = array_unique($value); 
$dupes = array_diff_key( $value, $unique ); - I tried this , but this will not return my expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array functions and ditch the foreach loops if you wish:

Here is a one-liner:

Code:

```
$value = [10, 10, 5, 8];
var_export(array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values($value),[1])));
```

As multi-line:

```
var_export(
    array_keys(
        array_intersect(
            array_count_values($value),
            [1]
        )
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 5,
  1 => 8,
)
```

This gets the value counts as an array, then uses `array_intersect()` to only retain values that occur once, then turns the keys into the values of a zero-index array.

The above snippet works identically to @modsfabio's and @axiac's answers.  The ONLY advantage in my snippet is brevity.  It is possible that their solutions may outperform mine, but judging speed on relatively small data sets may be a waste of dev time.  For anyone processing relatively large data sets, do your own benchmarking to find the technique that works best.

---

For lowest computational/time complexity, use a single loop and as you iterate conditionally populate a lookup array and `unset()` as needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7WFol)) ([Crosslink to my CodeReview answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269671/141885))

```
$values = [10, 10, 5, 8];

$found = [];
foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    if (!isset($found[$value])) {
        $found[$value] = $index;
    } else {
        unset($values[$index], $values[$found[$value]]);
    }
}
var_export($values);
// [2 => 5, 3 => 8]
```

A couple of notes:

1. If processing float values, using a technique that stores the values as keys (as all of my snippets do), then the results may be incorrect because php will change floats to integers when used as keys.
2. PHP is consistently much faster at searching for keys than it is at searching for values.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this using `array_count_values()` and a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php

$input = array(10,10,5,8);
$output = array();

foreach(array_count_values($input) as $value => $count)
{
    if($count == 1)
    {
        $output[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(5)
  [1]=>
  int(8)
}
```

Example: https://eval.in/819461

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach:

```
$value = array(10,10,5,8);
$output = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_count_values($value),
        function ($count) {
            return $count == 1;
        }
    )
)
```

[`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) produces an array that associates to each unique value from `$value` the number of times it appears in the array.

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) keeps in this result only the entries (the keys) that appear only once in the original array.

[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) produces the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get an array with how often every element occurs in the array. Then remove all the elements from the original array that occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), [array_search()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [unset()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) functions.

```
<?php
$value = array(10,10,5,8);
echo '<pre>';print_r($value);echo '</pre>';
$cnt = array_count_values($value);
$dup = array();
foreach ($cnt as $k => $repeated) {
    if ($repeated > 1) {
        if(($key = array_search($k, $value)) !== false) {
            unset($value[$key]);
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($cnt);echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';print_r($value);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/rW4W2vWo)

Comment: This doesn't give the wanted result

Comment: @modsfabio, thanks for your valuable comment. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Watch this snippet fail: https://3v4l.org/I9rQY  The code logic is simply flawed.

Answer (score -1):

you can use
    foreach loop 
and 
    array_diff() function:

```
$value=array(10,10,5,8);
$duplicated=array();
foreach($value as $k=>$v)
{
if($kt=array_search($v,$value))!==false and 
$k!=$kt)
{if (count(array_keys($array, $value)) > 1) 
{
 /* Execute code */
}
unset($value[$kt];$duplicated[]=$v;
}
}

$result=array_diff($values,$duplicated);
print_r($result);
```

output

Array([2]=>5[3]=>8)

Comment: This answer was not tested, has syntax errors, is poorly explained, and does not work.