# How to remove from a multidimensional array all duplicate elements including the original?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using php 7.1.

I have seen that to eliminate the duplicate elements it is enough with this

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

I've also seen this work

```
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

But that only deletes the elements that are duplicated from the array, I want to delete those that are duplicated but I don't want it to leave me only 1 without a duplicate, I want it to also delete that original on which it has been based to verify that it is duplicated

How could I do it?

For example i have this

```
$array = array(
    [0] = array(
        [id] => 1,
        [number] => 12345,
        [date] => 2022-05-09
    )
    [1] = array(
        [id] => 2,
        [number] => 123456,
        [date] => 2022-05-09
    )
    [2] = array(
        [id] => 3,
        [number] => 123456,
        [date] => 2022-05-09
    )
    [3] = array(
        [id] => 3,
        [number] => 123456,
        [date] => 2022-05-09
    )
)
```

How can i let it become this:?

```
    $array = array(
        [0] = array(
            [id] => 1,
            [number] => 12345,
            [date] => 2022-05-09
        )
        [1] = array(
            [id] => 2,
            [number] => 123456,
            [date] => 2022-05-09
        )
)
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622315/3484400)

Comment: @HassanPezeshk 
Thanks but that is for a 1-dimensional array, I don't know how to adapt it to my multidimensional array. 
it shows me error: Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be straightforward. Pluck all IDs using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and use [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get counts of occurrences of each ID. Then, use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter only unique ones.

```
<?php

$unique_ids = array_count_values(array_column($array,'id'));
$res = array_filter($array, fn($v) => $unique_ids[$v['id']] === 1);
print_r($res);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/42f6d)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the advice from [How to remove values from an array if occurring more than one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654446/2943403), for best time complexity, keep a lookup array of previously encountered values and their index.  When a value is encountered more than once, delete the current and original row from the input array.  It is perfectly safe to call `unset()` on an element that has already been `unset()`, no breakage will occur.

I have extended your input array to demonstrate that `unset()` will not cause trouble.  I am using "array destructuring" in the `foreach()` to make the code more concise.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8fuI7))

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'number' => 12345, 'date' => '2022-05-09'],
    ['id' => 2, 'number' => 123456, 'date' => '2022-05-09'],
    ['id' => 3, 'number' => 123456, 'date' => '2022-05-09'],
    ['id' => 3, 'number' => 123456, 'date' => '2022-05-09'],
    ['id' => 4, 'number' => 123457, 'date' => '2022-05-10'],
    ['id' => 4, 'number' => 123458, 'date' => '2022-05-11'],
    ['id' => 3, 'number' => 123459, 'date' => '2022-05-12']
];

$found = [];
foreach ($array as $index => ['id' => $id]) {
    if (isset($found[$id])) {
        unset($array[$index], $array[$found[$id]]);
    } else {
        $found[$id] = $index;
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'number' => 12345,
    'date' => '2022-05-09',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'number' => 123456,
    'date' => '2022-05-09',
  ),
)
```